# Issues with WebSite to WebApplication conversion

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I converted a website to a web application using visual studio 2017.After conversion the web application throws the following error.Is there any solution to this problem

> Parser Error Message: The file '/Global.asax.vb' does not exist.

Source Error:

> Line 1:  <%@ Application Inherits="WebApplication1.Test.Global"
>   Language="VB" CodeFile="Global.asax.vb" %

Answer (score 0):

Open NOTEPAD application with a blank document.

Paste the following code into it

```
Option Explicit On
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web.SessionState


Public Class Global_asax
  Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
  '
  Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
  End Sub

  Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the session is started
  End Sub

  Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
  End Sub

  Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires upon attempting to authenticate the use
  End Sub

  Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when an error occurs
  End Sub

  Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the session ends
  End Sub

  Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application ends
  End Sub

End Class
```

Save the file as GLOBAL.ASAX in the ROOT folder of your application where the code is.

Next which ever file has the error flagged it:

```
Line 1: <%@ Application Inherits="WebApplication1.Test.Global" Language="VB" CodeFile="Global.asax.vb" %>
```

Change that line to the below:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="WebApplication1.Test.Global" Language="VB" %>
```

Without seeing some of your code as there is no code posted, its difficult to nail it down straight away.

If you follow the above, it should get you past the error you displayed.

Comment: I tried the above solution but now it throws error on the startup page i mean the home page it looks something like this ,Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.Test1.wc_ModulesNavigation'.Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="WebApplication1.test1.wc_ModulesNavigation" Codebehind="wc_ModulesNavigation.ascx.vb" %>
Line 2:   <table>
Line 3:    <tr>

Comment: Sounds like some of your files are missing or not located where the compiler expected to find them... You really need to post some code from the your files and also a screen grab would be much better trying to paste the error info into the comments...